# Can't open couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am a beginner to CouchDB, I need to do a school assignment with it, but now it crashed on my computer. My system is mac os, when I open the couchDB application, it keeps popping new admin windows(http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/#login?urlback=), but all of them are failed to connect.

When I try:

> curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984

it returns

> ```
>  curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5984: Connection refused
> ```

It worked well on my computer before, seems after I tried to setup a remote node, it crashed.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: "seems after I tried to setup a remote node". What have you done? If you changed the CouchDB configuration, you can edit the configuration file and restart CouchDB service to fix it.

Comment: As you say, it crashed. You need to run it again.